# NaNs in Eigen3 quaternion returned by slerp()

Tags: c++, quaternions, eigen3

I've run into some weird behavior with Eigen3 quaternions. In the context of an application I'm developing, I occasionally call `slerp()` with two identical quaternions - sometimes as simple as having 1 for the real part and 0 for all the imaginary coefficients. The quaternion returned by `slerp()` has NaNs for all its coefficients. To make it more frustrating, I've written a simple `main()` that does nothing but manipulate similar quaternions. There, `slerp()` behaves as I would expect.

Has anyone else run into this?

In my application I've resorted to testing if the two quaternions pass the `isApprox()` test and skipping the call to `slerp()` if they do. This is okay as a bandaid, but I don't like the feeling that `slerp()` is going to similarly misbehave under slightly different circumstances.

Comment: You'll have to isolate the case when you get the NaNs. E.g. log the exact input values and try them in your simple `main`. Don't forget to log with enough precision to reproduce the numbers exactly, i.e. use `std::numeric_limits::max_digits10`.

Comment: @Ruslan I thought I had done exactly that, but it turned out I hadn't. Thanks for giving me the nudge that made me check some assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had inadvertently deleted an important `} else {` line in the code I was working on. This insured that the interpolation factor that I was passing to `slerp()` was the result of a divide-by-zero operation. In my simple test apparatus, the interpolation factor I was providing was what it should have been in the actual code.

Once again, the moral of the story is to make sure you're *actually* testing what you *think* you're testing.